# Moderators' role in profile deletion

Tags: support, moderators, deleted-accounts

When a user requests the deletion of their own profile, are moderators automatically informed about their  request?

Answer (score 15):

Moderators don't handle such deletions, and are not notified when a user requests deletion.

Deletion is *automatic* after 24 hours, [unless the account has cast a lot of votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted), then a support team employee handles the deletion, after review. The employees are notified of such specific cases, yes.