# Are votes preserved on meta sites when an active user is deleted?

Tags: support, voting, per-site-meta, deleted-accounts

Recently on one of my SE sites, a user who was a highly active voter (over 1000 votes on each of main and meta) deleted their account. As expected, there was no accompanying loss of rep for other users, since [votes are preserved and attributed to Community when a high-voting account is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/278659). But today I noticed that many posts on the per-site meta have scores 1 point below where they were before. This user actually had more votes on meta than anyone else, and it's a rather quiet meta site so losing all those votes, even from a single user, actually feels significant.

I don't know the threshold above which a user is considered "too highly voting" to have their votes removed together with their account, so let me first ask:

**Is there a threshold for not removing votes of a deleted active account on *meta* sites? Or are votes on meta *always* removed when an account is deleted?**

I'll save any possible feature-request for a follow-up post :-)

Comment: I could imagine this is not the case, as the main driver io moving votes to the community user was to avoid a loss of rep, and the privileges linked to that, as it would upset people to see their privileges be revoked due to a user quitting.

Comment: @Luuklag Losing votes on deserving posts is also an undesirable outcome (in the big picture, post score is more important than user rep!), but I can see this would only be a noticeable issue on smaller sites where a single user's votes can be significant.

Comment: I can totally see how meta votes are not considered at all.