# "Comments should be at least 15 characters in length" does not make clear @name might be excluded

Tags: discussion, android-app, comment-replies

I find the error message a bit misleading as it fails to explain that in this situation the *@username* isn't taken into account in the character count (since *@username* won't be displayed in the posted comment, [as username is the poster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation)):

[image]

[image]

Comment: You aren't supposed to tag OP's name in the comments...

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 I know (did you read the question?) but in the Android app when hitting the reply button it does tag OP's name in the comments...

Comment: Then eh, it's a bug? I don't think it's supposed to be like that. iOS app doesn't have this function. I do agree on a more clarified message.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 unsure, I was also hesitating tagging this question as a bug.

Comment: 5 down votes and no explanation, nice job!

Comment: +1 for valid issue, especially since the OP name is added automatically by the app itself. /cc @ArceusMaster

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt if you will change this question into feature request asking to not automatically add the OP's name when replying to his/her comment this might be more sensible to implement, and would likely gather more support from users i.e. upvotes. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it's a second (though very related) issue so I posted a second question for it http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264454/178179

Comment: People are weird. Why would a better and more clarified message be a bad idea? @Downvoters

Comment: I can't delete my downvote ;(

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Why do I keep getting told I posted less than 15 characters when I posted more than 15?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110305/why-do-i-keep-getting-told-i-posted-less-than-15-characters-when-i-posted-more-t) or [Should the minimum comment length check include “@username”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116019/should-the-minimum-comment-length-check-include-username)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The system lacks consistency and clarity when it comes to this point.

Whether you agree to the current explanation of Jeff why the *@username* gets stripped out or not, we still should make the system easy to understand to users. Who didn't count 10 times when he/she first saw this error message? At least I did.

So yes, the text should make the reason behind it clear. Another thing, not very related, I can think of is this: shouldn't it always strip out the *@username* when counting the characters? This will make the behavior easier to understand in all circumstances. Maybe I will do a feature request on this.

Comment: See [Should the minimum comment length check include “@username”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116019/should-the-minimum-comment-length-check-include-username) and [Why do I keep getting told I posted less than 15 characters when I posted more than 15?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110305/why-do-i-keep-getting-told-i-posted-less-than-15-characters-when-i-posted-more-t)

Comment: Indeed. This is totally confusing.