# Don't automatically add @name when replying to OP's comment in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, comments, android-app

When replying to a comment, the Android app automatically adds an `@name` to notify the original commenter. I find that a bit misleading when this original commenter is also the author of the question/answer, since then the `@name` [won't always be displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation) in the final comment. And also since the "Comments should be at least 15 characters" error message [fails to indicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264451/178179) that the OP's name isn't included in the count, which leads to weird situations:

> [image]

Comment: My vote is still for [Don't remove the @ part of my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment)...